# Can I use JRebel without java installed

Tags: java, jrebel

Will JRebeL work when only Eclipse's embedded java is used?

I don't otherwise have java insalled. Do I need to get it in order to use it?

Comment: Eclipse won't work if you don't have Java installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer from [JRebel Page](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/faq/)

> JRebel is

```
A Java development-time tool that decreases turnaround by instantly reloading changes to your code. All this without having to restart the container or redeploy the application.
A JVM -javaagent plugin. The -javaagent is a command line option that has been available since Java 5 to allow custom instrumentation plugins to be registered. JRebel uses this option for installation.
A single JAR file. That’s pretty much says it all – there is no long installation process: just unzip, copy, add options to the command line and enjoy!
```

> JRebel isn’t

```
An IDE plugin. JRebel comes pre-bundled with the plugins for Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, NetBeans and JDeveloper, however, JRebel agent is designed to be IDE-agnostic and can be used outside the IDE.
A framework. JRebel does not introduce any dependencies in your application. You can take it away at any moment and just continue developing the way you do normally.
An application server. JRebel works with all prominent application servers, but it definitely isn’t one.
A custom JVM. JRebel doesn’t require you to make any changes to the JVM and works on all prominent JVM implementations.
```